# Mower deck is losing power but the engine stays constant

Tags: lawn, lawn-mower, repair

I have a 2010 Toro MX5480 I’ve got an issue with.  The belt recently shredded, so I went to the dealer and bought a replacement and got it installed with no problem.  This seemed to create a new issue in which any kind of resistance while the blades are turned on quickly slows the blades down to a nearly total stop.  The engine on the mower continues to run at the same constant speed and does not die out at all, just the blades slow down.  What in the world is going on?

Comment: I think belt too long, misplaced (maybe with transport), or oil on belt (also maybe caused by transport, or over-oiling). 1- check that blades can rotate easily (switch off engine, be careful). 2- check the belt: it should not move easily if the blades are still. (careful, engine off)